# Do these challenge like things still exist?

Tags: discussion

So basically I stumbled upon this post: [What's the fastest and / or craziest way to model an arrow in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/whats-the-fastest-and-or-craziest-way-to-model-an-arrow-in-blender)
Also this one: [What's the fastest / most fun way to create a fork in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207755/whats-the-fastest-most-fun-way-to-create-a-fork-in-blender/207827#207827)

Now I am not completely sure whether this was some fun official challenge, or whether it was just a few members who came together an decided to have some fun.

Exactly what was this thing? Do you guys do this even today? Was this a popular thing? Or was it just a small period fad or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not official, any user is free to create them and they have been quite popular.

Strictly speaking they are off topic, but since they work well to improve community engagement we tend to turn a blind eye.

There are no official rules in place as long as they are not too frequent. I'd say at least:

1. Keep them infrequent enough to not lose appeal
2. Keep them on-topic and specifically about using Blender.
3. Word them in such way that if you remove the fact they are a "challenge" they are still valid, answerable and on topic
4. Try to make them as objective as possible.
5. Avoid overly broad topics. Make them interesting but relatively limited in scope that they can be answered in a short post